# Optimization: removing branch

Tags: c, math

I know a little C. I tried to write a program which uses no conditional statement but add odd numbers and multiply even numbers for a given array of integers. It was not very hard to write **if odd add n else add 0** part. But, I couldn't work it out for the multiplication part. The solution seems to be **multiply with 1 if odd else with n**.

So, my question is **given an integer, how you can transform it to 1 if it is odd else to the given integer. no conditional is allowed**. Or, a better idea if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually, you compile it with optimizations and let the compiler do this stuff for you. Unless you know it's a bottleneck (hint: unless you've profiled, you probably don't), doing this would be a premature optimization.

Comment: @colonel, thanks. I do not know if compilers can remove most branches. This problem is for academic reason. Not for production.

Comment: What about `res = (i % 2) + ((i+1) % 2) * number;`? Unless I misunderstood the question

Comment: You can compile it with `gcc -S` to view the generated assembly. Looks like gcc optimizes it to a conditional move with `-O2`.

Comment: @severin, you must be a genious. I wasted my entire day with it. What about writing it as a answer?

Comment: Smells like homework.

Comment: @sebastian, your sense of smell is very good. I would think the same. Unless you believe our teacher is just teaching **what is conditionals?** I have no way to prove the other way.

Comment: @sebastian, as I told, it's not a homework.

Comment: @silentboy no worries, just thought about adding the homework tag but eventually noticed it's gone, so nevermind :) I was just asking myself about the "why", like in "why are you asking it?"...

Comment: Thanks for brownie points, @silentboy. In fairness, answer by @bolov might be better by being slightly faster - compiler might compute `i%2` only once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, asked to provide an answer. Expression

```
res = (i % 2) + ((i+1) % 2) * number;
```

will return 1 if `i` is odd, and given `number` otherwise

Answer (score 4):

Without multiplication, assuming 2s complement arithmetic (cast i to unsigned if not):

```
/* implements odd(i) ? 1 : n */
(((i&1)-1)&(n-1)) + 1
```

- i&1 is 1 if i is odd, 0 otherwise, so
- (i&1)-1 is 0 if i is odd, -1 otherwise.
- Since the 2s-complement representation of -1 has all bits set to 1:
- ((i&1)-1)&(n-1) is 0 if i is odd, (n-1) otherwise, so
- (((i&1)-1)&(n-1))+1 is 1 if i is odd, n otherwise.

Whether that's faster than multiplication depends heavily on architecture; on modern CPUs it's doubtful, but on embedded architectures it would be. It certainly is not faster than a compiler-generated conditional move, and it's hardly easy to read. Still...

Answer (score 2):

So let me shamelessly rip off the comment of @SeverinPappadeux and change it a little bit so I can claim it as my own:

```
res = i % 2 + (1 - i % 2) * number;
      ^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^
odd:    1         0
even:   0         1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check last bit easily. This way, you know that number is odd or even.

```
last_bit = number & 0x01;
first_number = last_bit;
```

If last bit is zero, first number is zero. If not (odd), then it's 1.

Then you take last_bit and invert that last bit

```
last_bit = (last_bit+1) & 0x01;
second_number = last_bit * n;
```

Now second_number is either n or 0.

```
result = (first_number + second_number);
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
int Get1IfOddValOtherwise(int val)
{
    return (1-(val&1))*(val-1)+1;
}
```

Comment: (plus 1) Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
res = (i % 2) ? 1: number;
```

Conditional execution, or, branch predication is the best shot.

Small branches are not so evil nowadays.

**Edit**
It's branch predic**a**tion, not branch prediction.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predication

Comment: Isn't `?:` a inline branch?

Comment: @silentboy: on modern cpus, with simple right-hand expressions like this, it is usually a conditional move (CMOV on x86).

Comment: @silentboy Modern ISAs usually evaluates both sides of the small branches, and select the result of true side, as long as doing so is cheaper than actually jumping. In this case, the CPU just issues two conditional MOVs and let the condition to select which one's outcome is written to the register file. Trust me, branch prediction and conditional execution is available on much more CPUs than a hardware multiplier, let alone not all CPUs can complete int32 x int32 multiplication in 1 cycle, if any. This is as simple as a 3 instruction operation that takes 2 cycles, so don't make it fancy.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to know how to remove that branch. It seems with optimization issues in mind, your answer is good. And I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another multiplication-less version (that also assumes two's complement). The logic is to `&` the number with with 11...11 (-1) for even numbers (11...1x where *x* is *don't care* would work too... maybe that could be used somehow) and with 00...01 for odd numbers. The problem then boils down to transforming odd and even numbers into those masks.

```
n&(((n&1) << 1) - 1)
```

`(n&1) << 1` is 0 for even numbers and 2 for odd numbers. Subtracting one gives the desired masks.

(As said, you'd usually be better off doing `n % 2 ? n : 1` rather than trying to second-guess the optimizer though. The compiler might generate a branchless conditional move for that if it thinks it's worthwhile.)

Answer (score 0):

In other answers it was already pointed out that the indicator for odd and even is `i%2` and `(i+1)%2`.

You can use this to solve the full problem in one line:

```
result = (i%2)*(number+i)+((i+1)%2)*number*i
```

You have to care that `i` is never negative. If that remains possible, then you can normalize the situation by a double mod operation: `(2+i%2)%2` and `(2+(i+1)%2)%2`.

---

Of course, using the branching this can be made shorter as in

```
result = (i%2)?(i+number):(i*number)
```